# syntax error at or near "INSERT" when creating a temp table and insert into a subquery--PostgreSQL Error

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, temp-tables

I created a temp table and `insert into` a subquery but I got an error saying 'syntax error at or near "INSERT"'. Can anyone have idea? Thanks!

```
CREATE TABLE population_vaccinated2 
(
    continent VARCHAR(200),
    location VARCHAR(200),
    date DATE,
    population INT,
    new_vaccinations NUMERIC,
    aggre_vaccinations NUMERIC
)

INSERT INTO population_vaccinated2
    SELECT 
        dea.continent, dea.location, dea.date, dea.population, 
        vac.new_vaccinations,
        SUM(vac.new_vaccinations) OVER (PARTITION BY dea.location ORDER BY dea.location, dea.date) AS aggre_vaccinations 
    FROM 
        covid_deaths AS dea
    JOIN 
        covid_vaccinations AS vac ON dea.location = vac.location
                                  AND dea.date = vac.date
```

Comment: Have you tried terminating your statements with `;`

Comment: Yes. I add ; at the end of dea.date=vac.date still show me the same error

Comment: You need to terminate *every* statement -  the *create table* statement is not an exception.

Comment: Thanks! I made it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO` are **two distinct statements**. You need to insert a `;` between them:

```
...
)
;
INSERT INTO ...
```

> I created a temp table

Note that this is not a temporary table because you are missing the `TEMPORARY` keyword.

Comment: Thanks very much! I made it :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help. If my answer worked for you, you can set it to "accepted" so other people know it worked.

Comment: I set it. Sorry I am super new here and don't know much about the rule :)